# VueJS Unknown custom element with nested template in single file components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs2

I have a nested structure with vue:

```
<app>
  <column> : [array]
    <task> : [array]
      <resource> : [array]
```

I'm also using single file components.
For `<app>` component it looks like this (`/App.vue` file)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
     <column v-for=""></column>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import column from './components/Column'

  export default {
    name: 'project',
    components: {
      column
    },  
    data () {
      return {

      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The `<column>` component (`/components/Column.vue` file):

```
<template>
  <div>
      <task v-for=""></task>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import task from './Task'

  export default {
    name: 'column',
    components: {
      task
    },
    data () {
      return {

      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The `<task>` component (`/components/Task.vue` file):

```
<template>
  <div>
      <resources></resources>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { resources } from './Init-resource'

  export default {
    name: 'task',
    components: {
      resources
    },
    data () {
      return {

      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Up until this point everything works flawlessly. The app renders a bunch of columns, and inside the columns it renders tasks. 
But then comes another layer `<resource>`, that looks like this (`/components/Init-resource.vue` file):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <select>
      <option v-for=""></option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'resources',
    data () {
      return {

      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I get this error:

```
vue.common.js?e881:509 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <resources> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option. 
(found in component <task>
```

It doesn't recognize the last `<resource>` component. But everything looks fine, imports are correct, components are returned for the template...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found it. I used named import, so instead of this:

```
import { resources } from './Init-resource'
```

it should be this:

```
import resources from './Init-resource'
```